# How to extend namespace's interface

Tags: typescript

I made following namespace

```
declare namespace Dante {
  import Container from '$dante/components/Container';

  interface Component extends Container {
    dApplyProps?: (p: UnknownProps) => void;
    dApplyLayout?: () => void;
  }
}
```

I was under assumption that following would be valid

```
const myComponent: Dante.Component = /* .. */
myComponent.someContainerMethod()
```

However I get an error saying that `someContainerMethod` does not exist on `Dante.Component`. I assume I am extending interface incorrectly? It 100% exists in `Container`. It appears that none of the `Container` types are inherited.

Edit: `Container` is an ordinary ts class

Curiously this works, but I don't understand why it does and interface doesn't

```
type Component = Container & {
    dApplyProps?: (p: UnknownProps) => void;
    dApplyLayout?: () => void;
}
```

Comment: looks like you aren't exporting your interface to me. try `export interface` instead of just `interface`

Comment: @r3wt doesn't seem to do the trick, exported everything, restarted ts server, only that approach with merged types works.